# Set dataframe row value to a numpy array value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

***Edited version of original post***

I have a dataframe that's entirely populated with NaN. Specifically:

```
print(histPrice['Allocation %'])

[Output]: 
 Symbols    SPY  GLD  TLT   MA   QQQ      TIP
Date                                         
2019-11-01  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-31  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-30  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-29  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-28  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-25  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-24  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-23  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-22  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-21  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
2019-10-18  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
```

I have the following `numpy` array:

```
x = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.2])
```

I tried assigning the array to 2019-10-30 row by:

```
histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x
```

as well as

```
histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2,:] = x
```

Yet, both result in:

```
print(histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2])

[Output]: 
 Symbols
SPY       NaN
GLD       NaN
TLT       NaN
MA        NaN
QQQ       NaN
TIP       NaN
Name: 2019-10-30 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

I'm baffled as to why it's still outputting `NaN`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are u trying to replace every third row of table with np array?

Comment: @Tserenjamts i'm just trying to replace a specific row with an array

Comment: histPrice is of what type?

Comment: @aprilangel histPrice is 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

Comment: @Drive2blue but it looks like histPrice['Allocation %'] is a dataframe as well

Comment: @aprilangel Correct, so ```Allocation %``` is a dataframe within another dataframe, ```histPrice```. As a matter of fact, that appears to be the issue. Using ```iloc``` or ```loc``` to assign value invariably fails to update the value. However, if I run the same logic at the parent level (histPrice), it works. I'll update my post with additional details on what I mean. You pointed me to something that I may have been overlooking this whole time! Thank you!!

Comment: @Drive2blue Hey, Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need `loc` with indexing of `df.index`:

```
histPrice.loc[df.index[2], 'Allocation %'] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
df.iloc[2,:]=a[0]
df
Out[142]: 
        Stock: Bond: Gold:
2/01/19    NaN   NaN   NaN
1/31/19    NaN   NaN   NaN
1/30/19    33%   33%   33%
1/29/19    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This didn't work. See section "Additional Details" in my updated post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the whole row with your numpy array, you should be able to use:

```py
x = np.array([2,3,1])
df.iloc[2]= x

        Stock Bond Gold
2/01/19   NaN  NaN  NaN
1/31/19   NaN  NaN  NaN
1/30/19     2    3    1
1/29/19   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This will update the row with each value of the array, and not just the first value.

I am curious if this will work for you?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Bond','Gold'], index=['2/01/19','1/31/19','1/30/19','1/29/19'])
histPrice = {}
histPrice['Allocation %'] = df
x = np.array([2,3,1])
histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x 
print(histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2])
```

Comment: This didn't work. See section "Additional Details" in my updated post

Comment: @drive2blue It looks like you are trying to assign the array to one column histPrice['Allocation %'], and not a  row.

Comment: @drive2blue do you have a dataframe saved in a dictionary?

Comment: @Drive2blue Based on your updated question, I am wondering if you have one or more dataframes stored in a dictionary. Is there a chance you are updating the wrong dataframe (I only ask because you reference two different dataframes in your updated question: histPrice['Allocation %'], histPrice['RP Allocation %'])?

Comment: there is only one dataframe, "Allocation %". Sorry about the confusion. I revised the post accordingly

Comment: @Drive2blue Not a problem at all.  What is _histPrice_?

Comment: histPrice is 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

Comment: @Drive2blue Hmm I'm afraid I don't fully understand how your dataframe is structured. If histPrice is a Pandas DataFrame, then using histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x would mean you are trying to assign the numpy array to index 2, of the column 'Allocation %', and only that column (i.e. not the row).

Comment: You pointed me to something that I may have been overlooking this whole time. To clarify, ```Allocation %``` is a dataframe within another dataframe, ```histPrice```. As a matter of fact, that appears to be the issue. Using iloc or loc to assign value invariably fails to update the value. However, if I run the same logic at the parent level (histPrice), it works. I'll update my post with additional details on what I mean. Thank you so much for all your time and help!

Comment: @Drive2blue I was wondering if there was a nested dataframe, and I was even looking into storing dataframes within dataframes as that is a new concept for me.  I'm glad I was still able to help though.

Comment: And how to insert, say, `2x10` array into 2 dataframe rows? I tried using `df.loc[['row1', 'row2'], :] = my_array` but it throws an error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the description, you are storing a dataframe in another single row dataframe.

And when doing below, You are setting an value in the copy of your dataframe.

```
histPrice['Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x
```

Instead, try: (you can replace the 0 with your index)

```
histPrice.loc[0, 'Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x
```

Comment: hmmm, I tried your suggestion but got ```KeyError: 'Allocation %' ``` Instead, I tried ```histPrice.loc[ : , 'Allocation %'].iloc[2] = x``` but that resulted in ```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence```  :(

Comment: @Drive2blue don't use array, set x as a list. should be fine =)